# Name of the book/series based on magicians who tap into computer grid?

Tags: story-identification, books

Fantasy/scifi combo - band of travelers who must get from "sphere" or domain to domain - each geographic area is ruled by a magician - it turns out later these are people who are unwittingly tapping into the computer grid they all live on to alter their own reality?

Comment: A time frame of when read or published would be helpful.  Any additional details on the 'travelers' (ages, sexes, etc) ?

Answer (score 10):

This could be from *The Soul Rider* series by Jack Chalker:

```
Spirits of Flux and Anchor, Tor Books, 1984 (ISBN 0-8125-3320-8)
Empires of Flux and Anchor, Tor Books, 1984 (ISBN 0-8125-3329-1)
Masters of Flux and Anchor, Tor Books, January, 1985 (ISBN 0-8125-3281-3)
The Birth of Flux and Anchor, Tor Books, 1985 (ISBN 0-8125-2292-3)
Children of Flux and Anchor, Tor Books, September, 1986 (ISBN 0-8125-2340-7)
```

The prequel novel, *The Birth of Flux and Anchor*, explains the (forgotten) technological underpinnings of the 'magic' powers that allow adepts to create realities ('anchors') out of 'Flux'.

Comment: That's it!!!  This site is genius….(and so are you!)  Thanks for the good night's sleep I'll have since trying to remember…. :)

Comment: If this is the answer, you might want to mark it as accepted.