# I am looking for an older series about space colonization

Tags: story-identification

Way back in high school I read a series about colonization of other planets. In the books, contact was lost with the rest of the civilization and over time people with mathematical ability were able to control the computers that were doing the terraforming...and later came to be seen as wizards.  I cannot for the life of me remember the author or title...can anyone help?

Comment: @Otis Good catch, but I did the duplication the other way since the answer to this one is better.

Comment: @Otis I meant [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/63551/31394) is better than [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/46003/31394). Note that [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/170496/31394) didn't exist when I left that comment.

Answer (score 12):

It's hard to be sure, because the level of detail is scant, but one series I know of that meets your stated criteria is the [Soul Rider](https://www.goodreads.com/series/41590-soul-rider) series by [Jack Chalker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Chalker).

The intro from book 5 gives a nice description of the series;

> But only the wizards of World, those with the power, could command
>   anything from those great machines, and they were as limited as
>   always. None could again get into the great control rooms of the
>   ancients nor speak directly to the tremendous thinking machines that
>   ran everything automatically. The Gates themselves were almost an
>   afterthought; they had been closed, and set to "outgoing," but they
>   had been locked.
>
> Nobody really knew how they worked, or how to use them, and the
>   computers had been strictly  limited by the ancients so that even if
>   they possessed that knowledge they could neither release or reveal it.

[image]

Comment: Yup thats the series...thanks much!

Comment: Don't forget to click the check button to accept his answer if it's correct.